# Regex for bank transaction parsing

Tags: regex, ruby, banking

How do I parse and extract the 4 important columns from a text table of the following format? These are bank transaction line items extracted from a PDF using Ruby's `pdf-reader` package - as you can see the spacing between columns is very irregular between various columns.

```
11/4                      Stripe Transfer St-XYZ Agnostic Computers                      582.30
11/4                      Recurring Payment authorized on 11/01 Digitalocean.Com                                           12.00
11/4                      Purchase authorized on 11/01 Google *Gsuite_Get                                                  24.00
11/4                      Purchase authorized on 11/02 Amazon Web Service                                                 460.15
11/4                      Purchase authorized on 11/02 Amazon Web Service                                                   8.07           2,903.09
11/5                      Recurring Payment authorized on 11/03 Atlassian                                                  15.00           2,888.09
11/6                      Recurring Payment authorized on 11/04 Pipedrive Inc NY NY                                        24.00           2,864.09
11/12                     Foobar Retail Dis 211011 ABCDEFGH                            8,031.44
11/12                     Wire Trans Svc Charge - Sequence: 999999999999 Srf#                                              45.00
11/12                     WT 211012-999999 ABCD Bank Limited /Bnf=FOOBARINC                                             5,000.00           5,850.53
11/14                      Purchase authorized on 11/13 Microconf Microconf.Com MN                                            100.00           5,702.53
```

The above transactions are extracted from a bank PDF with the following visual layout
[image: Table column names]

Need to parse the **bold** colums via a regexp:

1. **Date** - dd/mm format - always present
2. Check number - always empty and may be ignored (alphanumeric single word?)
3. **Description** - Text with dates, numbers, special characters - always present
4. **Credits** - currency amount (only for deposits)
5. **Debits** - currency amount (only for payments)
6. Balance - currency amount (appears sporadically, not important)

I have only been able to get as far as `/^(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2})\s+/mg` for extracting the mm/dd. Should I start chomping the amounts from the right, but then there are no clear seperator patterns!

Comment: 100% agree, but my bank only makes CSVs available for past 18 months, and these are for older years which is only available as month-wise PDFs.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would show the desired result for your example, given as a Ruby object (e.g., an array of hashes). What are the rules for identifying a credit and a debit? Please be more precise in defining the description. Is it any sequence of digits, or two sequences of digits separated by a hyphen? If so, must the hyphen be in a certain location? For "check number" you  say, "alphanumeric single word?". How could the reader possibly know? Your job is to give us precise rules for identifying the strings you wish to extract. Without that we can be of no help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spacing between the columns is irregular but always seems to be more than 2. In that case you can use 3 capture group and an optional 4th part with also a capture group for the Debits part.

```
^(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2})\s{2,}(\S.*?)\s{2,}(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*\.\d{2})(?:\s{2,}(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*\.\d{2}))?
```

In parts the pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2})\s{2,}` Capture **group 1** Match 1,2 digits `/` 1,2 digits and 2 or more whitespace chars
- `(\S.*?)\s{2,}` Capture **group 2** Match at least a single non whitespace chars and as least as possible characters until the next occurrence of 2 or more whitespace chars
- `(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*\.\d{2})` Capture **group 3** Match the number format
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\s{2,}` Match 2 or more whitespace chars
  - `(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*\.\d{2})` Capture **group 4**, match the number format
- `)?` Close the non capture group and make it optional

See a [rubular regex demo](https://rubular.com/r/lPWkWkpnazxwjP)

Comment: Thanks so much. This was the most lightweight, non-brittle solution as it gets the "The spacing between the columns is irregular but always seems to be more than 2" subtlety right. I was able to add named labels to the capture segments you suggested and add a dash of readability.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming your target is as csv/spreadsheet entries
[image]

It is best to tackle the task in stages, and my preferred target format is CSV for a spreadsheet

TL;DR see last comment

```
11/4                      Stripe Transfer St-XYZ Agnostic Computers                      582.30
11/4                      Recurring Payment authorized on 11/01 Digitalocean.Com                                                 12.00
11/4                      Purchase authorized on 11/01 Google *Gsuite_Get                                                        24.00
11/4                      Purchase authorized on 11/02 Amazon Web Service                                                       460.15
11/4                      Purchase authorized on 11/02 Amazon Web Service                                                         8.07           2,903.09
11/5                      Recurring Payment authorized on 11/03 Atlassian                                                        15.00           2,888.09
11/6                      Recurring Payment authorized on 11/04 Pipedrive Inc NY NY                                              24.00           2,864.09
11/12                     Foobar Retail Dis 211011 ABCDEFGH                            8,031.44
11/12                     Wire Trans Svc Charge - Sequence: 999999999999 Srf#                                                    45.00
11/12                     WT 211012-999999 ABCD Bank Limited /Bnf=FOOBARINC                                                   5,000.00           5,850.53
11/14                      Purchase authorized on 11/13 Microconf Microconf.Com MN                                                  100.00           5,702.53
```

1st we can target the bigger gaps so pick a suitable width, don't worry about the staggers they will be resolved later.
                                             to become            `??.??`                          
We either need to protect existing commas so replace those with another unused symbol say `~` or for currency best to delete them from between numbers.

Replace all line ends with dummy extensions, it will not matter if there are too many columns if not digits so use
    `??.??    ??.??` (yes in this case we assume under 1000 and cannot use , # or *)

thus `11/4                      Stripe Transfer St-XYZ Agnostic Computers                      582.30`
becomes  `11/4                      Stripe Transfer St-XYZ Agnostic Computers                      582.30    ??.??    ??.??`

```
11/4                      Stripe Transfer St-XYZ Agnostic Computers                      582.30    ??.??    ??.??
11/4                      Recurring Payment authorized on 11/01 Digitalocean.Com            ??.??                                12.00    ??.??    ??.??
11/4                      Purchase authorized on 11/01 Google *Gsuite_Get            ??.??                                       24.00    ??.??    ??.??
11/4                      Purchase authorized on 11/02 Amazon Web Service            ??.??                                      460.15    ??.??    ??.??
11/4                      Purchase authorized on 11/02 Amazon Web Service            ??.??                                        8.07           2903.09    ??.??    ??.??
11/5                      Recurring Payment authorized on 11/03 Atlassian            ??.??                                       15.00           2888.09    ??.??    ??.??
11/6                      Recurring Payment authorized on 11/04 Pipedrive Inc NY NY            ??.??                             24.00           2864.09    ??.??    ??.??
11/12                     Foobar Retail Dis 211011 ABCDEFGH                            8031.44    ??.??    ??.??
11/12                     Wire Trans Svc Charge - Sequence: 999999999999 Srf#            ??.??                                   45.00    ??.??    ??.??
11/12                     WT 211012-999999 ABCD Bank Limited /Bnf=FOOBARINC            ??.??                                  5000.00           5850.53    ??.??    ??.??
11/14                      Purchase authorized on 11/13 Microconf Microconf.Com MN            ??.??                           100.00           5702.53    ??.??    ??.??
```

Now we can target the remaining irregular white space so replace all larger spaces with 2 or 3 spaces as appropriate (usually 2 will do, but beware any description with double spaces.)

```
11/4   Stripe Transfer St-XYZ Agnostic Computers   582.30   ??.??  ??.??
11/4   Recurring Payment authorized on 11/01 Digitalocean.Com  ??.??   12.00   ??.??  ??.??
11/4   Purchase authorized on 11/01 Google *Gsuite_Get  ??.??   24.00   ??.??  ??.??
11/4   Purchase authorized on 11/02 Amazon Web Service  ??.??   460.15   ??.??  ??.??
11/4   Purchase authorized on 11/02 Amazon Web Service  ??.??   8.07  2903.09   ??.??  ??.??
11/5   Recurring Payment authorized on 11/03 Atlassian  ??.??   15.00  2888.09   ??.??  ??.??
11/6   Recurring Payment authorized on 11/04 Pipedrive Inc NY NY  ??.??   24.00  2864.09   ??.??  ??.??
11/12   Foobar Retail Dis 211011 ABCDEFGH   8031.44   ??.??  ??.??
11/12   Wire Trans Svc Charge - Sequence: 999999999999 Srf#  ??.??   45.00   ??.??  ??.??
11/12   WT 211012-999999 ABCD Bank Limited /Bnf=FOOBARINC  ??.??   5000.00  5850.53   ??.??  ??.??
11/14   Purchase authorized on 11/13 Microconf Microconf.Com MN  ??.??   100.00  5702.53   ??.??  ??.??
```

Finally add headers, replace     with comma separators and remove the ??.??

```
Date,Description,Credits,Debits,Balance,,,

11/4,Stripe Transfer St-XYZ Agnostic Computers,582.30,,
11/4,Recurring Payment authorized on 11/01 Digitalocean.Com,,12.00,,
11/4,Purchase authorized on 11/01 Google *Gsuite_Get,,24.00,,
11/4,Purchase authorized on 11/02 Amazon Web Service,,460.15,,
11/4,Purchase authorized on 11/02 Amazon Web Service,,8.07,2903.09,,
11/5,Recurring Payment authorized on 11/03 Atlassian,,15.00,2888.09,,
11/6,Recurring Payment authorized on 11/04 Pipedrive Inc NY NY,,24.00,2864.09,,
11/12,Foobar Retail Dis 211011 ABCDEFGH,8031.44,,
11/12,Wire Trans Svc Charge - Sequence: 999999999999 Srf#,,45.00,,
11/12,WT 211012-999999 ABCD Bank Limited /Bnf=FOOBARINC,,5000.00,5850.53,,
11/14,Purchase authorized on 11/13 Microconf Microconf.Com MN,,100.00,5702.53,,
```

On import to the spreadsheet the headers and possibly currency need a style.

In hindsight I realised all you need to do is

1. Remove commas
2. Inject a dummy column 3 in big white spaces (even a single ~)
3. Pare down spaces to 2x space then replace those 2 spaces with comma
4. Remove dummy entry e.g. the ~
5. Add header `Date,Description,Credits,Debits,Balance`

The rest will take care of itself.

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

Your main problem is that if you're dealing with string data *after* you've parsed it from the PDF, so it's difficult to determine which positional elements correspond with which field. You really ought to open a separate question about how to solve this at PDF parse time, rather than trying to parse the text after the PDF parsing phase. That said, below is a solution that works with the limited sample you provided, and that should at least get you started with the string parsing you're attempting to do.

### Assumptions and Examples

From your example, it looks like there are some implicit business rules to your format:

1. Some fields are *always* present (e.g. date and description).
2. Only one debit or credit will be be on each line.
3. Each line will have a maximum of 4/5 populated fields.

However, even if "balance" isn't important, you can't really tell whether something is a credit or a debit without reference to some existing balance or clearly-defined number of spaces in the parsed output, so you either need to fix your input data or PDF parsing to ensure you *always* have a balance (which you could possibly calculate at PDF parsing time) or ensure you know the specific field widths that are in the PDF layout or the parsed output from the PDF.

While only a partial solution which you will need to update for your real use cases, you could create a Struct or other object to hold your data, and then make additional parsing decisions based on how many fields or spaces between fields that each transaction holds. A potential solution follows.

#### Example Using Your String from the PDF Parse

*NB: The code examples below have been aggressively wrapped to 60 characters whenever it won't affect the results to reduce side-scrolling within StackOverflow code blocks. Feel free to reflow the code to suit your own style choices.*

We'll start by storing the parsed text you provided in your original post in a here-document for exercising the rest of this code example.

```rb
text_extracted_from_pdf = <<~'EXTRACTED_TEXT'
  11/4                      Stripe Transfer St-XYZ Agnostic Computers                      582.30
  11/4                      Recurring Payment authorized on 11/01 Digitalocean.Com                                           12.00
  11/4                      Purchase authorized on 11/01 Google *Gsuite_Get                                                  24.00
  11/4                      Purchase authorized on 11/02 Amazon Web Service                                                 460.15
  11/4                      Purchase authorized on 11/02 Amazon Web Service                                                   8.07           2,903.09
  11/5                      Recurring Payment authorized on 11/03 Atlassian                                                  15.00           2,888.09
  11/6                      Recurring Payment authorized on 11/04 Pipedrive Inc NY NY                                        24.00           2,864.09
  11/12                     Foobar Retail Dis 211011 ABCDEFGH                            8,031.44
  11/12                     Wire Trans Svc Charge - Sequence: 999999999999 Srf#                                              45.00
  11/12                     WT 211012-999999 ABCD Bank Limited /Bnf=FOOBARINC                                             5,000.00           5,850.53
  11/14                      Purchase authorized on 11/13 Microconf Microconf.Com MN                                            100.00           5,702.53
EXTRACTED_TEXT
```

We'll also define some constants that we'll use to parse your extracted text after the PDF parse, and a [Struct](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Struct.html) class to hold the results of parsing each line of text. You may need to adjust these based on your real data.

```rb
# This describes what a currency item looks like after your
# PDF parse.
MONEY_FMT = /\b[\d,]+\.\d{2}\b/

# Make some assumptions about fixed-width fields. These
# values seem reliable given the sample string data from
# your original post.
LN_START_TO_LAST_CRED_CHR = /^.{92}\.\d{2}$?/
LN_START_TO_END_OF_DEBIT  = /^.{93,}#{MONEY_FMT}$?/

Transaction = Struct.new(:date, :description, :credit,
                         :debit, :balance, keyword_init:
                         true)
```

Now we read the output from the PDF parse to try to analyze the resulting string. Using Ruby 3.1.1, and with code aggressively wrapped to minimize side-scrolling on StackOverflow:

```rb
transactions = []
text_extracted_from_pdf.each_line do
  fields = _1.split /\s{2,}/

  date, description = fields.shift 2
  balance = fields.pop.chomp if fields.count == 2

  # This violates our rule of 4/5 populated fields.
  raise "too many fields remaining: #{fields.count}" unless
    fields.count == 1

  # Match on characters from start of line to end of credit.
  credit =
    fields.pop.chomp if _1.match? LN_START_TO_LAST_CRED_CHR

  # Match on characters from start of line to end of debit.
  debit =
    fields.pop.chomp if _1.match? LN_START_TO_END_OF_DEBIT

  transactions << Transaction.new({date: date, description:
                                   description, credit:
                                   credit, debit: debit,
                                   balance: balance})
end
```

##### Expected Result

The *transactions* array should now hold a collection of Transaction objects which you can iterate over as needed. For example, the example code above populates the *transactions* Array with the following Struct objects:

```rb
transactions
#=> 
[#<struct Transaction date="11/4", description="Stripe Transfer St-XYZ Agnostic Computers", credit="582.30", debit=nil, balance=nil>,
 #<struct Transaction date="11/4", description="Recurring Payment authorized on 11/01 Digitalocean.Com", credit=nil, debit="12.00", balance=nil>,
 #<struct Transaction date="11/4", description="Purchase authorized on 11/01 Google *Gsuite_Get", credit=nil, debit="24.00", balance=nil>,
 #<struct Transaction date="11/4", description="Purchase authorized on 11/02 Amazon Web Service", credit=nil, debit="460.15", balance=nil>,
 #<struct Transaction date="11/4", description="Purchase authorized on 11/02 Amazon Web Service", credit=nil, debit="8.07", balance="2,903.09">,
 #<struct Transaction date="11/5", description="Recurring Payment authorized on 11/03 Atlassian", credit=nil, debit="15.00", balance="2,888.09">,
 #<struct Transaction date="11/6", description="Recurring Payment authorized on 11/04 Pipedrive Inc NY NY", credit=nil, debit="24.00", balance="2,864.09">,
 #<struct Transaction date="11/12", description="Foobar Retail Dis 211011 ABCDEFGH", credit="8,031.44", debit=nil, balance=nil>,
 #<struct Transaction date="11/12", description="Wire Trans Svc Charge - Sequence: 999999999999 Srf#", credit=nil, debit="45.00", balance=nil>,
 #<struct Transaction date="11/12", description="WT 211012-999999 ABCD Bank Limited /Bnf=FOOBARINC", credit=nil, debit="5,000.00", balance="5,850.53">,
 #<struct Transaction date="11/14", description="Purchase authorized on 11/13 Microconf Microconf.Com MN", credit=nil, debit="100.00", balance="5,702.53">]
```

##### Validate Your String Parse

A lot of things can go wrong when people make assumptions about either formatting or their code's logic. If you want to validate your Struct objects, you can iterate over the collection to identify bad parses, or you could choose to log, warn, or raise an exception inside your parsing loop above.

```rb
# If you have parsed both a credit and a debit on the same line,
# something's wrong.
transactions.map do
  warn "bad parse for #{_1}" if _1.credit && _1.debit
end.compact!
#=> []
```

Instead of simply raising a warning here, you could also use [Array#reject!](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Array.html#method-i-reject-21) to remove items directly from *transactions* which didn't parse properly, assuming you don't simply skip adding them to the collection in the first place within the #each_line loop above. How you choose to identify and handle a bad parse is really up to you; this is just one of many approaches, and is meant to illustrate that you need to validate the results of each PDF or string parse *somewhere* in your code.

Comment: Thanks so much. The validating of debit v/ credit part of your solution was really educative for me, and I have used it to verify internal sanity. The regexes themselves    needed more debugging on adding a longer list of transactions, so I have used another solution - much gratitude neverthless for the patient help.